# Using Python to loop contents of a CSV

Tags: python, csv

In Python I want to list out each number inside a simple CSV...

CSV:

```
07555555555, 07555555551
```

This is what I have tried:

```
for number in csv.reader(instance.data_file.read().splitlines()):
    print(number)
```

However, this outputs the whole thing as one string like this...

```
['07446164630', '07755555555']
```

Why?

I have also tried to loop like this

```
for i, item in enumerate(csv.reader(instance.data_file.read().splitlines())):
    print(i)
    print(item)
```

I'm not sure I fully understand what I'm doing wrong so any help in explaining how to print each number in the file would be amazing.

Comment: You can iterate the list you are getting while reading the csv file and print it.

Comment: @TanveerAlam thanks, is that the correct way tho seems too simple? I also assumed thats what enumerate would do, but had not joy.

Comment: Your `csv` has just a line of 2 elements so it  is returning just a list of two elements like `print(['07446164630', '07755555555'])`

Comment: @OrbiterFleet : Yes you can read rows which returns list which can be iterated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`csv.reader` parses each line of a CSV, so your loop is iterating over the *lines* of the CSV file. Since both numbers are in one line, you get them in one array. If you want to iterate on the values of each line, use another, nested `for` loop.:

```
for line in csv.reader(instance.data_file.read().splitlines()):
    for item in line:
        number = int(item)
        print(number) # or whatever you want
```

Or using `enumerate` to get the indices of each number:

```
for line in csv.reader(instance.data_file.read().splitlines()):
    for index, item in enumerate(line):
        number = int(item)
        print(index, number) # or whatever you want
```

Comment: @OrbiterFleet Yes, `enumerate` can be used with any list.

Comment: If this solves your question, feel free to click the checkmark to the left. Or you can wait for another answer that you might like more.

Answer (score -1):

Use **numpy's flatten** module to convert matrices to 1D arrays:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.loadtxt(file_name, delimiter=',').flatten()
for item in data: print(item)
```

Comment: A bit overkill, don't you think? Also, he didn't say what should happen when there is more than one line. It may or not be what he intends.